# Error when deploying contract using ethers v6

Tags: solidity, ethers.js

I'm using ethers v6 and am trying to deploy a contract. I have the contract ABI and bytecode which I got from compiling the contract using Hardhat.

Here's the code which is failing at the last line:

```
const provider = new ethers.BrowserProvider(window.ethereum, 11155111) 
const signer = await provider.getSigner()
const factory = new ethers.ContractFactory(contractAbi, contractByteCode, signer)
let contract = await factory.deploy(hash, tPlayerTwoAddress)
```

Contract ABI:

```
[{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_c1","type":"uint8"},{"name":"_c2","type":"uint8"}],"name":"win","outputs":[{"name":"w","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"j2Timeout","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"stake","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"c2","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint8"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"c1Hash","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bytes32"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_c2","type":"uint8"}],"name":"play","outputs":[],"payable":true,"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"j2","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"lastAction","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_c1","type":"uint8"},{"name":"_salt","type":"uint256"}],"name":"solve","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"j1","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"j1Timeout","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"TIMEOUT","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"name":"_c1Hash","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"_j2","type":"address"}],"payable":true,"stateMutability":"payable","type":"constructor"}]
```

Contract bytecode:

```
  const contractByteCode = "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"
```

And yes I've made sure I'm using the bytecode and not the deployedBytecode from hardhat.

The error I'm getting is:

```
page.js:182 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')
    at #walkAsync (fragments.js:596:20)
    at ParamType.walkAsync (fragments.js:613:24)
    at eval (contract.js:131:22)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at resolveArgs (contract.js:130:37)
    at ContractFactory.getDeployTransaction (factory.js:75:93)
    at ContractFactory.deploy (factory.js:88:31)
    at createNewGame (page.js:176:36)
```

The contract itself has no issues as it was deployed [successfully](https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0x42Fa56a30F0a6e9FC2D56bf6543Ca5dC4dD9Cf9e#code) using hardhat but I need to get it to work using ethers.

**EDIT:** My hash variable in `await factory.deploy(hash, tPlayerTwoAddress)` was undefined. That was the issue.